# Python sort files by filename with numbers as first letters

Tags: python, list, sorting

I have the following list which is the output of `mylist.sort()`

```
['0_sound.wav', '10_sound.wav', '15_sound.wav', '20_sound.wav', '5_sound.wav']
```

This makes sense, since the filenames are treated as strings. But I want the following order:

```
['0_sound.wav', '5_sound.wav', '10_sound.wav', '15_sound.wav', '20_sound.wav']
```

What is a good way of archieving this? The filename may vary, it´s not always "sound", which would make it easier.

Comment: Will there always be this `_` as a separator between the number and the word?

Comment: yes, that will always be the same

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that there will always be an underscore `_` as a separator:

```
files = ['0_sound.wav', '10_sound.wav', '15_sound.wav', '20_sound.wav', '5_sound.wav']
files.sort(key=lambda x: int(x.split('_')[0]))
```

Result:

```
['0_sound.wav', '5_sound.wav', '10_sound.wav', '15_sound.wav', '20_sound.wav']
```

Note: This will fail if there are unexpected filenames that don't have this separator or that don't start with a number, if that is even possible I would suggest filtering that list first so you don't get unexpected errors

Comment: thank you, that lambda function as key is pretty cool